# MySQLI mysqli_store_result results with Malformed Packet error

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am in the process of converting some old MySQL code into MySQLI Prepared Statements and hit a snag:
If I run the same SQL code as prepared statement, I get a "Malformed Package" error. This happens even with extremely simple queries like "SELECT * FROM [TableName]".

I have the creation of the connection and setting of the Report level in a Seperate file altogether. So that code must be identicaly by definition.

As specific example, this code works:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM AngebotsDB";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

But this code:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM AngebotsDB";
// $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
mysqli_execute($stmt);
$resultReference = mysqli_store_result($link); //throws exception
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($resultReference);
```

ends in:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 
'Malformed packet' in /home/cgroschupff/public_html/custom_code/DB 
structure.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /home/cgroschupff/public_html/custom_code/DB structure.php(16): 
mysqli_store_result(Object(mysqli)) #1 {main} thrown in 
/home/cgroschupff/public_html/custom_code/DB structure.php on line 16
```

All I could really find is some old information of this happening when Connecting to the DB.

Note that the used MySQLi/PHP version is rather old (5.2.17?). So this could be a "long ago fixed" bug?

Comment: Not sure whether I offered it to you before or not, but consider to use PDO instead of mysqli. It will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: `mysqli_store_result` is not [`mysqli_stmt_store_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)

Comment: I have to stay in a MySQLi Procedural Style as close to the existing MySQL as possible. The primary goal (for now) is just to get rid of the "MySQL is deprecated" Warning. Prepaded statements are a longterm goal that I hoped I could  get done without to many changes.
mysqli_stmt_store_result is a totally different way to access the data.
The end result must be processable with almost the same code as the Current mySQL Resultset. Minor reworks (using null rather then false to check for no next row) is possible. But not a complete rework.

Comment: Well I pity you. A classical case of getting a LOT more trouble by choosing a seemingly easier road. This current trouble is just a start. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initialize a statement than you have to call other functions according to `mysqli_stmt` class so your code should be .

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM AngebotsDB";
   $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
   mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   $resultReference = mysqli_stmt_store_result($link);
```

Now if you try `var_dump($resultReference)` than return `true` or false .

if you want to show result with `mysqli_fetch_array` so you have to pass `mysqli_result` parameter so for this you have to use `mysqli_stmt_get_result`  .

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM AngebotsDB";
   $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
   mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt) ;
   $output = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ;
```

Now you can see `var_dump($output)` than you have result .

Comment: I marked your code as answer, even though I can not actually run it. Apparently running the development environment in the pre 5.3 means functions like mysqli_stmt_get_result() are missing.
I think I just reached what I can do without a upgrade of the Development environment. A pity, but currently unavoidable.

Comment: Sorry for i didn't  notice `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` version support. Please post  your correct  answer .